# $this->PageTitle в Yii2?

Tags: php, yii2

Как установить значение `title` из **контроллера**? Yii2

Comment: А чем во `view` не устраивает?

Comment: И чем не устраивает `$this->title`?

Comment: @Onedev.Link почему то не работает.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

На сколько я знаю, в `yii2` отказались от установки тайтла в контроллере и перенесли это действие во `view`.

В представлении можно сделать так:
`$this->title = "Мой заголовок";`

Если уж так хочется задавать заголовок в контроллере, то, скорее всего, придется в нем определить переменную, в которую записать значение и передать её в представление:

```
$title = 'Мой заголовок';
return $this->render('myPage', ['title' => $title]);
```

А во `view` написать:

`$this->title = $title;`

Answer (score 0):

```
class SiteController extends Controller
{
    public function actionIndex()
    {
        $this->getView()->title = 'Мой заголовок';
        return $this->render('index');
    }
}
```